# ElasticSearch stored field

Tags: elasticsearch

Is is absurd to store some fields while `_source` is already enabled? In documentation of elasticsearch [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html) as it is specified fields are not stored by defult but we can retrieve them from `_source`, If we set a field as stored while `_source` is also enabled, will there be duplicate of this field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will be stored twice.Field store is used to speed up the process .Instead of fetching _source and fetch the field will be slower than stored fields.It will directly fetch data from stored field.

Comment: And it is stated, stored fields are placed at index so it does not need to go to fetch it from the storage area, it can retrieve it just from place where index exist. Is this true? If this is true, suppose we try to retrieve two fields which of one is stored other one is not stored. Hence, it will fetch field not stored from `_source` and we will have no advantage. In order to have advantage of stored fields we should retrieve fields where all of them is stored. Am I right for these claims?